# Выбор рандомного элемента в Collection

Tags: java, коллекции

Как выбрать рандомный элемент в коллекции? Пробовал через toArray(), а дальше выбирал и кастовал, там не получалось прикастовать Object[] к Player[].

Comment: В огороде бузина, в Киевщине дядька. В чем суть вопроса то?

Comment: У вас Player массив или коллекция? Как вы пытались? почему не воспользоваться shuffle?

Comment: Коллекция примерно выглядит так: Collection <? extends Player> players = ...

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на en.SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092086/get-random-element-from-collection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У коллекции всегда можно узнать размер:

Необходимо получить индекс случайного элемента

```
  Random rnd = new Random();
  int i = rnd.nextInt(myCollection.size());
  player = (Player)(myCollection.toArray() [i]);
```